# cannot print data from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

According to the tutorial, `print(data.head())` is supposed to print out first five rows of the csv file. but there is no output. I did some research but i didn't understand the solutions people gave.

```
import tensorflow
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_table("student-por.csv", sep=";")

print(data.head())
```

I also tried `df.head()` and it didn't work either.
The csv was from [this website](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance).

Comment: Is delimiter/sep a `;` instead of a `,`?

Comment: please provide a snippet from the text file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please, provide the code inside the question, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use sep, it's what I see the most.And it is more consistent with other functions such as to_csv, which does not accept delimiter, only sep.  I hope this would be helpful..

Comment: The csv file is seperated by ":". So, I put `sep=";"` after the file path

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
pd.read_table(file_path)
```

instead of pd.read_csv() function.

Comment: can you give some  more details of your code and the dataset?

Comment: i got the data from that website. Hope it helps you understand.